# Obj createTextNode changes the position of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

The 'boxObj' was created dynamically, with styles i have defined for it.
Now, I created the 'boxObjInDiv' with its own styles and appended it to the parent 'boxObj'
and everything was fine until i decided to add some text to 'boxObjInDiv' like you can see in the two lines commented as 'TROUBLE' below, and that's because the all 'boxObj' position changed all of a sudden and went down something like 100px..
how can i deal with it? it obvious that it happens when i use those two lines.

Oh and another thing, how can i right and left auto margin this 'Flower' text i added
so it will shown in the middle of it's 'boxObjInDiv' parent, i tried: 
newContent.className(..) with a margin attribute but it didn't work.

class box belongs to 'boxObj'

css:

```
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 175px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.lastBoxObjInDiv{
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    height: 35px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 35px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 35px;
}
```

js:

```
boxObj.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/lastBox.png')";
var boxObjInDiv = document.createElement('div');
boxObjInDiv.className = 'lastBoxObjInDiv';
var newContent = document.createTextNode("Flowers");  //TROUBLE
boxObjInDiv.appendChild(newContent);                  //TROUBLE
boxObj.appendChild(boxObjInDiv);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle?  It seems to work exactly the same for me with or without those two lines:  http://jsfiddle.net/9h7hp/

Comment: boxObj is the last box witch created (in a loop) while there are 5 boxes created before it and each of them gets the .box style. all the six boxes are positioned inside a section

Comment: this last box position is fine but when i add text to it like shown, its positioning changing..

Comment: Again, can you reproduce it in the jsfiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/9h7hp/1/  There seems to be no issue here, without being able to reproduce it, it's really hard to fix it.